# Is it possible to access an element in an unordered_map without making a copy of it?

Tags: c++

I have an extremely performance-intensive application where I would really like to avoid making a copy of a string that is kept in an unordered_map. An example of what I want to be able to do is to compare this string to a local string variable.

E.g.,

```
unordered_map<string,string> X;
string test = "def";
X["abc"] = test;

//other operations here...

string* map_entry = X.???; //some operation that doesn't make a copy of the string

size_t map_entry_size = (*map_entry).size();

for (size_t i = 0; i < map_entry_size; ++i)
{
if ((*map_entry)[i] != test[i])
  throw 1;
}
```

Is this possible, or must I always make a copy of the element before using it?

Comment: not clear why you think you need to make a copy. `operator[]` returns a reference, not a copy...

Comment: Dereferencing an iterator returns a reference, so you don't have copy there.

Comment: unrelated: if you ever need to avoid a copy use a reference not a pointer to safe you some unnecessary headace

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that I was assigning the result to a string. Using a reference solves the problem, although it complicates my code a bit due to other considerations.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 4):

The `[]` operator will return a reference or const reference, so no copy there. Iterators will give you a reference to a `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` so again there is no copy there.

```
std::string &map_entry = X["abc"]; // Reference to value, no copy
std::string *map_entry = &X["abc"]; // If you need a pointer
```

If you really need a pointer, doing `&map["key"]` or `&iterator->second` is valid.

If your looking for performance though, avoiding or at least being careful with a `std::string` as a key is a far more significant gain especially if the keys are not very short.

Certainly dont think just because an unordered map is `O(1)` that a `std::unordered_map<std::string, T>` is nearly as fast as using say integer keys, and its even further away from dense integer keys that could just be a normal array (even though both would also be `O(1)`).

- You need to make a `std::string` temporary. Worst case this is a dynamic memory allocation. For small strings the standard library implementation your using may have a "small string optimisation", but thats still a copy.

  If possible you want to use an existing `std::string` you had already made from somewhere.
- You need to compute the hash (default uses `std::hash`) and for strings that is `O(n)` with the string length.

  `std::string` doesnt have the means to cache its hash, so reusing (e.g. a constant/static) `std::string` doesnt avoid this, allthough you could make your own string wrapper that does.
- Because hashes may clash, if `unordered_map` does find an entry, it then needs to do a full string comparison anyway just in case, which is again `O(n)` with the string length (so actually not finding anything at all is faster than finding the right thing).

Using say an integer or other small fixed-size key (also consider if you know your strings are always less than say 4 or 8 bytes, you can just make that an integer with "null padding") makes the hash a simple piece of maths, and the comparison a single operation.

Using dense integers (say an enum form 0 to 16) allows you to use an array and array indexing is very very fast.